# How to create a socket that is accessible across different networks

Tags: python, sockets

Below I have two scripts that work when I bind the `server.py` to my computers IPV4 address and connect the `client.py` to that same address. The next step I'm trying to take is the ability to use this socket across different networks. I thought that it would be as simple as changing the value of `SERVER` to my public IP address (which can be found by clicking [this link](http://icanhazip.com/)). When I make that change, I get this error upon running `server.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmbra\Downloads\Python Programs\Concepts\Sockets\server.py", line 13, in <module>
    server.bind(ADDRESS)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

### server.py

```
import socket
import threading

PORT = 5050
# SERVER = '192.168.0.30'
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())  # Change this to the public IP address to allow access across multiple networks
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)
HEADER = 64  # The number of bytes expected to get from the client
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # AF_INET is the type of addresses we are looking for
server.bind(ADDRESS)


def handle_client(conn, address):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {address} connected.")

    while True:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)  # This line also blocks until it receives a message
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                conn.close()
                break

            print(f'[{address}] {msg}')
            conn.send("Message Received".encode(FORMAT))


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}.')
    while True:
        conn, address = server.accept()  # This line will wait until it finds a connection.
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, address))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}.")


print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

### client.py

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'
SERVER = "192.168.0.30"
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDRESS)


# The pickle module could be used to send objects instead of strings.
def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    # For some reason we have to send a byte string first with the integer size of the message, concatenated with spaces
    # until it hits the length of the header.
    send_length = str(len(message)).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' '*(HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))


while True:
    message_ = input('Message: ')
    send(message_)
    if message_ == "!DISCONNECT":
        break
```

What must I do to make this work across different networks?

Comment: set `SERVER` to `''` in `server.py` to indicate that the port should be accessible from any of the server's networks.  (note that if your PC is behind a firewall, the firewall will still block incoming TCP connection as usual, though)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Then what should I connect client.py to?

Comment: @GabeMorris the router's public IP. But the router has to configured to forward connection from the WAN to the LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server socket can bind only to an IP that is local to the machine it is running on (or, to the wildcard IP `0.0.0.0` to bind to all available local IPs). Clients running on the same network can connect to the server via any LAN IP/Port the server is bound to.

However, when the server machine is not directly connected to the Internet, but is running behind a router/proxy, the server socket cannot bind to the network's public IP. So, for what you are attempting, you need to bind the server socket to its local LAN IP (or wildcard) and Port, and then configure the network router to **port-forward** inbound connections from its public WAN IP/Port to the server's private LAN IP/Port. Then, clients running on other networks can connect to your public WAN IP/Port, and then be forwarded to the server.

If the router supports UPnP (Universal Play-by-play) and it is enabled, the server code can programmably setup the port forwarding rules dynamically. Otherwise, the rules  need to be configured manually in the router's configuration by an admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, I won't be able to configure the current network to forward any connections because I don't have administrative access. If I were to have access to this network, would I type in the router's IP address into my browser and configure the settings there?

Comment: @GabeMorris that depends on the router's software and config. Most routers can be configured by browser, but only when connected to on the LAN side. Using the LAN IP will work, sometimes a domain name works, too (ie, I have an Asus router, and can enter `router.asus.com` in my browser). Typically, access can also be opened on the WAN side too, if remote access is needed. And some routers can also be configured by mobile app over Wifi.